# Can't link a JS script generated from a Kotlin/JS project using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, kotlin

As stated above, the problem is that I can't link the compiled JS code from a Kotlin project (called `twf`) to my web-project. No matter what I try, Chrome outputs an error such as `twf.stringToExpression is not a function`

As far as I'm concerned, the Kotlin code does compile correctly, and the beginning of an output file `twf.js` looks as follows:

```
if (typeof kotlin === 'undefined') {
throw new Error("Error loading module 'twf'. Its dependency 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'twf'.");
}var twf = function (_, Kotlin) {
'use strict';
var setOf = Kotlin.kotlin.collections.setOf_mh5how$;
...
```

Which means that variable `twf` does exist. Also, in the same file I found this:

```
function stringToExpression(string, scope, isMathMl, functionConfiguration, compiledConfiguration) {
if (scope === void 0)
  ...
if (isMathMl === void 0)
  ...
if (functionConfiguration === void 0) {
  ...
}if (compiledConfiguration === void 0)
  ...
```

So the function exists and I can call it with only a string as an input, just like I do in the `index.html` file (I know that having a bare script inside an HTML file is a bad habit, but it is only a prototype):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  var testTaskString = "a-b/c";
  console.log(twf.stringToExpression(testTaskString));
  ...
</script>
```

Nevertheless, I still get the error I mentioned above and I don't seem to know with to do about it. How do I solve it?

P.S. This is the `<head>` part of the page (both `kotlin.js` and `twf.js` are linked):

```
<title>PixiJS Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="lib/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="lib/kotlin.js"></script>
<script src="lib/twf.js"></script>
```

P.P.S. I even put `@JsName("stringToExpression")` before the function in the Kotlin code before compilation, but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this question was just an another instance of the *"look through the code that you are using more carefully"* problem, since the solution was quite trivial. When I used the `console.log(twf)` command (since I was sure that the `twf` variable was declared) I get the following output:

```
> Object
  > api:
    ...
    > stringToExpression: ƒ stringToExpression( ... )
    ...
  > baseoperations:
  ...
```

Hence, as far as I'm concered and as far as it works, I had to use the following code to refer to the function instead:

```
var testTaskString = "a-b/c";
console.log(twf.api.stringToExpression(testTaskString));
```